# Not able to install cider in emacs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, emacs, clojure

I'm following the steps as [mentioned here](https://github.com/flyingmachine/emacs-for-clojure/), to configure emacs for clojure development. 
I downloaded the github repository and copied the contents to /home/gx/.emacs.d

And followed till step 5.
When I run M-x package-install cider I'm getting **[No match]**

Below is my .emacs.d/init.el file:

```
;;;;
;; Packages
;;;;

;; Define package repositories
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("tromey" . "http://tromey.com/elpa/") t)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") t)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa-stable" . "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/") t)

(add-to-list 'package-pinned-packages '(cider . "melpa-stable") t)




;; Load and activate emacs packages. Do this first so that the
;; packages are loaded before you start trying to modify them.
;; This also sets the load path.
(package-initialize)
```

I'm using Ubuntu.
My folder structure as below:
/home/gx/
................Desktop 
................Documents 
................Downloads 
............... .emacs.d 
........................customizations 
........................elpa 
........................init.el 
........................README.md 
........................themes 
................Videos 
................Music 
................Pictures

Answer (score 1):

The Brave Clojure book is great, but it's Emacs setup is really out of date.  CIDER has evolved so much since that book was written.

Follow the official CIDER documentation and you will be able to get Clojure support working very quickly.
https://docs.cider.mx/cider/basics/installation.html

Or if you want to have a Vim experience with Emacs and CIDER, then take a look at 
https://practicalli.github.io/spacemacs/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it's due to emacs being unable to get elpa packages. I added this to the top of my .emacs file:

`(setq gnutls-algorithm-priority "NORMAL:-VERS-TLS1.3")`

I'm not sure whether you need to explicitly add the elpa package sources, but if you want to be thorough:

`(add-to-list 'package-archives '("elpa" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/"))`